# How to generate previous month first date in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I used timeShift function `(${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-01'T'00:00:00.000'Z',,-P1M,,)})` to generate the previous month first date but the `jmeter` was still print the current month's first date.

I also tried `${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-01,,,-P1M)}` and `${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-01,,P1M,-)}` but with these functions as well `jmeter` was printing current month's date.

How can I generate previous month's first date in `jmeter` using `timeShift` function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use __timeShift() function for this. As per [Duration.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) javadoc

> The sections have suffixes in ASCII of "D", "H", "**M**" and "S" for days, hours, **minutes** and seconds, accepted in upper or lower case.

So you're subtracting 1 minute, not 1 month.

My expectation is that you should go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), something like:

```
${__groovy(java.time.LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).with(java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00.000'Z'"),)}
```

should do the trick for you:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)